# PostgreSQL PANIC: WAL contains references to invalid pages

Tags: postgresql, panic

I have problem with PostgreSQL database running as replica of the master database server. Database on master runs without any problems. But replica database runs only for few hours (it is random time) and after that crashing down by this reason:

```
WARNING:  page 3318889 of relation base/16389/19632 is uninitialized
...
PANIC:  WAL contains references to invalid pages
```

Have you any idea what is wrong please? I'm not able to solve this problem for many days! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There was more Postgres bugs with these symptoms. Lot of was fixed already. Please, check if your Postgres is latest minor release. And if it is, then report this issue to mailing list  https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/.

Comment: Good hint with the minor version of the release. We have 9.4.12 but latest minor version of 9.4 is 9.4.25 maybe this is can be the problem. Thanks.